# Sencha extjs attribute scope

Tags: javascript, extjs

Currently I am working with extjs 3.4 and I am encountering the following problem. I am creating a GridPanel in the constructur i set a variable name called "bla" with the value "test2" after i have set this attribute i alert it to be sure it's been set properly. This works !. However when a button has been pressed in my gridpanel it cant read the bla attribute anymore and says its "undefined".

I've skipped the parts of the code that dont make sense to the question ;)

See the code below

```
    Ext.define('SC.view.WorkOrderHourGrid' ,{

    extend: 'Ext.grid.GridPanel',

    bla:"test",
    tbar: null,

    store:null,
    plugins:null,

    //Methods


    constructor:function(p_Store,config){
        this.tbar = this.buildTbar();
        this.bla = " test2";
        this.store = p_Store;

        //alerting bla attribute outputs test 2 !!
        alert(this.bla);


        var rowEditor = new Ext.ux.grid.RowEditor({
            saveText: 'Update'
        });

        this.plugins = [rowEditor];


        SC.view.WorkOrderHourGrid.superclass.constructor.call(this,config);
    },
    buildTbar:function()
    {
        return [{
            text: 'Toevoegen',
            handler: function(){
                tryOut();
            },
            //the button i was talking about
            handler:this.onAdd


        }];
    },
    onAdd:function(btn, ev)
    {
        //this outputs undefined !!!
        alert(this.bla);
    }


});
```

Comment: i think the this scope is refering to the button, not to the grid, thats why this happens. Check for `this.refOwner.bla` or try searching that component by id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope in the **onAdd** function is the button. That is why
**bla** is undefined.

Try to change your buildTbar function like so:

```
buildTbar:function()
{
    return [{
        text: 'Toevoegen',
        scope: this,
        //the button i was talking about
        handler:this.onAdd


    }];
},
```

I have not tested it! :)

Comment: Thanks works, I find it odd it does execute the method of the extended gridpanel class since this shouldn't be in the scope than 2 right ?

Comment: It can be a bit confusing. The "scope" param tells in which scope the handler is executed in, who would normally run in the scope of the component; the "this" (used in this.onAdd, and the scope) simply is the grid :)